# Array initialization

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

I have a 3-D array `[8][8][1002]`, which remains static with every run(values don't change).
Each page of array contains binary combination (8x8 matrix).

The array will take a lot of time to load, which I want to avoid.

Any way to reduce the time taken?

Or any other data structure may work effectively faster?

UPDATE:

The initialization of array is done by exhaustive method :

```
Loop1 for i:
  Loop2 for j:
   Loop3 for k:
   array[i][j][k]=1 //or 0 some logic
```

By loading, I mean array initialization.

Comment: If it's static why would it take any time to load?

Comment: How are you loading the array?

Comment: What's the Java tag for?

Comment: If you don't want it to take any time then initialize it with immediate values. This makes your code larger (much), but eliminates the issue you're discussing. You can use a simple code generator to output the init code. Loading it from a file might be faster as well, you could serialize it.

Comment: @DaveNewton I thought of using files, but may be it will be a bit inconvenient for this huge structure.Not sure though.

Comment: In fact, the bottleneck problem seems to be in *some logic* that you use to define the value for your array. Apart of this, I assume you have used a decent profiler to verify that the array loading is in fact a real bottleneck in your application.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The logic  isn't the problem, the values of 1's nd zero's are predefined.Its some what like different solutions how 8 kings can be arranged on a chessboard.I hope indexing the array wont create much problem.

Comment: Then your problem may lie somewhere else in your code. Have you checked your application using a profiler to spot the real bottlenecks in your app or you're just doing some random guessing to discover where the bottleneck may be?

Comment: Nothing as such, just a common sense, it should take a lot of time indeed. @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: Then I can bet a cookie that your real bottleneck is not in the array loading :). I recommend you to use a profiler for your application like VisualVM that already comes since JDK 6. If you're using JDK 7 u 40, you can use Java Mission Control, which comes with this and later distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to initialize with 0, so you don't need to write any init code, before default value is `0` when you creating an instance of array:

```
final int[][][] array = new int[1][1][1];
System.out.println(array[0][0][0]);
```

The result is: `0`

Comment: Hmm interesting, so have to work only on selective ones.

Answer (score 0):

If speed is a must, try declaring the array as final, and initialize it while you create it. That'll take a lot of code but will probably be faster.

```
final int[][][] array = {...}
```